# Bypassing "int main(int argc, char** argv)" in SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working on an crossplatform Opengl 4.5 / DirectX library in C++; for mac osx and linux, I would like to use SDL2 with an ogl renderer, and for windows, I would like to implement a directx renderer with wgl. Problem is that SDL requires access to "int main(int argc, char** args)" and won't let me define WinMain because of some init code it has in SDLmain. Any suggestions ?

PS: I get the error

```
unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) in VS2015.
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but the second parameter of `main` is conventionally called `argv`, not `args`.

Comment: sry; my bad. I was just programming in JAVA 10 minutes earlier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to define `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` before including `SDL.h` e.g.

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"
```

see https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady

Comment: hmm... I've never heard of that; just one more thing: would you recommend seperating Dx API and SDL api with macros ?

Comment: If by that you mean to have different implementations on different platforms, you could use the preprocessor directives as you suggest, but over time you'll want to largely isolate the platform specific parts in different files.

Comment: yes of course; things like shaders (hlsl oppesed to glsl) must be kept seperate, but things that the user will access(like scene graphs, meshes) will be built over those things